# PHP определение кодировки

Tags: php

Есть скрипт что пытается определить кодировку и сменить на WINDOWS-1251.
Вот основной кусок:

```
$from = mb_detect_encoding($cell,"auto");
print_r($from);echo"\n";
$cell = iconv( $from, "WINDOWS-1251//IGNORE", $cell );
```

Кто догадался, так происходит с каждой ячейкой одного из xls файла.
В общем, вторая строка с принтом, показывает, что ASCII.
По результату видно *брюкозабры*, что свидетельствует о не правильном определение кодировки и дальнейших действий.

Я долго, возможно не достаточно, гуглил, и пришел к проверки этих двух строчек:

```
print_r(mb_list_encodings());
print_r(mb_detect_order());
```

Вторая отдает скромненький массивчик:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASCII
    [1] => UTF-8
)
```

Первая [значительно больше](http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.supported-encodings.php).
Причем в зависимости от версии PHP список чуть-чуть меняется.
Сперва грешил на это, но потом открыл файл в OpenOffice, который даже не предложил выбрать кодировки.
Установил какое расширение, где выбрал `латин-1 => кирилица`, и все гуд.
То есть `latin-1`, подумал я, [но он есть, как понял, в любой версии](http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.supported-encodings.php#115682).

Хотел первой строчкой получать список и подсовывать его в `mb_detect_encoding`, но там еще есть какой то [порядок](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-order.php#example-3017).

В общем я запутался уже...

Подскажите как нормально определить кодировку?
Или дополните по моему сабжу, если не получилось полной каши.

Спасибо.

**UPD1**:
Сегодня пробовал:

```
print_r(mb_check_encoding($cell,"WINDOWS-1251"));
print_r(mb_check_encoding($cell,"ASCII"));
print_r(mb_check_encoding($cell,"WINDOWS-1252"));
print_r(mb_check_encoding($cell,"UTF-8"));
print_r(mb_check_encoding($cell,"ISO-8859-1"));
```

Все отдают **1**.
Что означает?
Кодировка не верна или подходит любая??

Comment: Все правильно, получаете список и суете его в mb_detect_encoding, она определяет порядок ваших кодировок, и затем используете первое значение из массива для конвертации в. Самые первый в списке будет наиболее "включающая кодировка" (та, что включает в себя остальные)

Comment: Кодировку лучше не определять, а знать все определялки буду давать погрешность в определении т.к. Многие кодировки пересекаются к примеру UTF8 до 128 символа это ASCII один в один т.е. по одному байту на символ в итоге mb_detect не знает что выбрать. По этому совет сначала определите вручную кодировку а потом уже приводите из исходной в требуемую.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память латин-1 вообще не поддерживает кириллицу.

Comment: Посмотрите что будет вот так: `mb_detect_order(mb_list_encodings());
print_r(mb_detect_order());`

Comment: @ilyaplot, не оно (и не отработало), там же как минимум какой то порядок нужен, на сколько я понял.

Comment: Попробуйте что-то навроде http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8 и конвертируйте все в UTF8, хотя исходя из этого определить начальную кодировку очень сложно - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or